# Como faço para autenticar o login no banco de dados?

Tags: python, sqlite3

estou criando uma aplicação de estudos para uma simples tela de login, na tela preta mesmo. Eu criei 2 arquivos, um onde crio as query do banco e outro com o código da aplicação em si. Possui duas tarefas, login e registro. O de registro está funcionando perfeitamente. Porém não consegui bolar a lógica para autenticação. Fiz um select, mandei imprimir para testar e ele está retornando certo.

query sql

```
def select_db(self, username, password):
        self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE username = ? AND password = ?',
                            (username, password))
```

código da aplicação

```
def login():
    db = Database('login.db')
    print('\n  ** ENTER WITH YOUR USERNAME **')
    username = input('  Username: ')
    password = getpass.getpass('  Password: ')
    auth = db.select_db(username, password)
    if username and password in auth:
        print('\n  Welcome to system!')
    else:
        print('\n  Login error! Try again!')
        login()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [fetchone](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone) do cursor para trazer o primeiro resultado da query, ela será a linha com os dados do usuário ou `None` caso não encontre:

```
def select_db(self, username, password):
    return self.cursor.execute(...).fetchone()
```

Depois disso precisa ajustar o seu `if`:

```
user = db.select_db(username, password)
if user:
     print('\n  Welcome to system!')
```

Comment: Foi na lata hein! To me sentindo mal pela minha burrice, rs. Obrigadão, resolveu!